# ajax hash navigation is not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, hash, navigation

I want to use hashes for my navigation but my script keeps resetting the initial hash to #home everytime the page loads no matter what hash i add in the url:

here is the script that fires to test if the hash exists and what to load inside of #content:

```
$page = $('#content');
if(window.location.hash == 'home') {        
    $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
    $("#content").createHomeEntry();
} else if(window.location.hash == 'news') {
    $xmlFile = 'xml/news.xml';
    $("#content").createNewsEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == 'biography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/bio.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == 'awards'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/awards.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == 'discography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/discography.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
}else{
    alert('this should fire off because there is no hash but it doesnt');
    $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
    $("#content").createHomeEntry();
}
```

Can somoeone help me here or maybe tell me why this script is setting #home as default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

window.location.hash returns the hash with the number sign.

This can be fixed using 1 of 4 methods. I also remove the first `if` which wasn't needed.

### Method #1 (best): Remove # from the hash property

```
$page = $('#content');
var hash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
if(hash == 'news') {
    $xmlFile = 'xml/news.xml';
    $("#content").createNewsEntry();
} else if (hash == 'biography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/bio.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (hash == 'awards'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/awards.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (hash == 'discography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/discography.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
}else{
    alert('this should fire off because there is no hash but it doesnt');
    $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
    $("#content").createHomeEntry();
}
```

### Method #2 (most efficient): Use a switch and `substr` the hash

```
$page = $('#content');
switch (window.location.hash.substr(1)) {
    case 'news':
        $xmlFile = 'xml/news.xml';
        $("#content").createNewsEntry();
        break;
    case 'biography':
        $xmlFile = 'xml/bio.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
        break;
    case 'awards':
        $xmlFile = 'xml/awards.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
        break;
    case 'discography':
        $xmlFile = 'xml/discography.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
        break;
    default:
        alert('this should fire off because there is no hash but it doesnt');
        $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
        $("#content").createHomeEntry();
        break;
}
```

### Method #3 (easiest): Add the hash

```
$page = $('#content');
if(window.location.hash == '#news') {
    $xmlFile = 'xml/news.xml';
    $("#content").createNewsEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == '#biography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/bio.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == '#awards'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/awards.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
} else if (window.location.hash == '#discography'){
    $xmlFile = 'xml/discography.xml';
    $("#content").createBioEntry();
}else{
    alert('this should fire off because there is no hash but it doesnt');
    $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
    $("#content").createHomeEntry();
}
```

### Method #4 (worst): Use `indexOf`

```
$page = $('#content');
    if(window.location.hash.indexOf('news') === 1) {
        $xmlFile = 'xml/news.xml';
        $("#content").createNewsEntry();
    } else if (window.location.hash.indexOf('biography') === 1){
        $xmlFile = 'xml/bio.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
    } else if (window.location.hash.indexOf('awards') === 1){
        $xmlFile = 'xml/awards.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
    } else if (window.location.hash.indexOf('discography') === 1){
        $xmlFile = 'xml/discography.xml';
        $("#content").createBioEntry();
    }else{
        alert('this should fire off because there is no hash but it doesnt');
        $xmlFile = 'xml/home.xml';
        $("#content").createHomeEntry();
    }
```

Comment: I tried both but neither solution worked. I stheir more information I can give you? whenever i type the url and add #news and hit enter in the url it reverts everything back and changes the hash to #home also loading the home content

Comment: I updated Method 1. Try that. Try alerting `hash` and make sure its value is what you need.

Comment: @DJERock Look here: http://jsfiddle.net/e4YSz/show/#awards.
The code: http://jsfiddle.net/e4YSz

Comment: I did not try methods two and three but Method 1 worked like a charm!!! Thanks for your help!

Comment: You are welcome! I just added the other Methods, just to show that there are many ways you could of fixed this.

Comment: You don't have to but maybe listing a situation type to use each method would help others, just a thought. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Here

```
window.location.hash == 'home'
```

It Returns not "home", it returns #home.
Substr your hash, or use it with #.
And for debuging use `alert(window.location.hash);`